# Обособленные определения

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую после "индивидуальное"?

Производство существующее, возрождающееся, строящееся, большое, среднее, малое, индивидуальное должно в соответствии с рыночными условиями выпускать только то, что имеет постоянный, а не одноразовый спрос, то, что приносит постоянную, а не одноразовую прибыль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, запятая ставится МЕЖДУ однородными членами, а не после них.